# How to set collection to null in Blueprism

Tags: collections, blueprism, rpa

How to set collection value to null by using a calculation tool? What's the expression to set collection to Null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and easy way to do it is to drag a new, blank Collection into your flow, and use a Calculation stage to set your working collection to the contents of the blank Collection:

[image]